# Enforcing password policy in AEM

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

How to do I override the weak password policy in AEM6 SP2 and enforce a custom strict password policy for admin as well as non admin editors ?

Answer (score -1):

Sreekanth  wrote this in an blog Article "AEM 61 - Touch UI Add Simple Password Policy" 
you can find it here:
http://experience-aem.blogspot.de/2015/09/aem-61-touch-ui-add-simple-password-policy.html

```
(function ($, $document) {
var ADMIN_PASSWORD_DIV = "#admin_password",
    FIELD_CHANGE_PASSWORD = ".change-user-password", // change password form
    FIELD_NEW_USER_PASSWORD = ".user-password-fields", //new user form
    BUTTON_OK = ".user-admin-change-password",  // change password form
    BUTTON_SAVE = ".user-admin-save-user", //new user form
    RE_TYPE_PASSWORD_FIELD = "[name='rep:re-password']";

var $policyText = $("<div/>").css('padding-bottom', '10px')
                            .css('font-style', 'italic')
                            .css('text-align', 'center')
                            .html('New Password must contain a number');

$(ADMIN_PASSWORD_DIV).find(".coral-Modal-body")
                    .prepend($policyText);

$(ADMIN_PASSWORD_DIV).find(RE_TYPE_PASSWORD_FIELD).focusout(focusHandler);

$(FIELD_NEW_USER_PASSWORD).find(RE_TYPE_PASSWORD_FIELD).focusout(focusHandler);

//change password form
$document.on("keyup", FIELD_CHANGE_PASSWORD, function(){
    keyHandler($(FIELD_CHANGE_PASSWORD));
});

//new user form
$document.on("keyup.user-admin change.user-admin selected.user-admin", ".save-button-enabler", function(){
    keyHandler( $(FIELD_NEW_USER_PASSWORD).find("[type=password]"));
});

function keyHandler($fields){
    if(!$fields || $fields.length != 2){
        return;
    }

    var one = $($fields[0]).val(), two = $($fields[1]).val();

    if(isValidPassword(one) && isValidPassword(two) && (one == two)){
        return;
    }

    $(BUTTON_OK).attr("disabled", "disabled"); // change password form
    $(BUTTON_SAVE).attr("disabled", "disabled"); //new user form
}

function focusHandler(event){
    clearErrors();

    var val = $(event.currentTarget).val();

    if(isValidPassword(val)){
        return;
    }

    var message = "Password must contain a number";

    showErrorAlert(message);
}

function clearErrors(){
    $(BUTTON_OK).removeAttr("disabled");   // change password form
    $(BUTTON_SAVE).removeAttr("disabled");  //new user form
}

function isValidPassword(text){
    if(!text){
        return true;
    }

    //check for number in text
    return /\d/.test(text);
}

function showErrorAlert(message, title){
    var fui = $(window).adaptTo("foundation-ui"),
        options = [{
            text: "OK",
            warning: true
        }];

    title = title || "Error";

    fui.prompt(title, message, "notice", options);

    $(BUTTON_OK).attr("disabled", "disabled"); // change password form
    $(BUTTON_SAVE).attr("disabled", "disabled"); //new user form
}})(jQuery, jQuery(document));
```

Comment: Please try to be more elaborate.